# Connecting Rime network to the Internet

Tags: networking, contiki

I have been playing with Contiki for some time now and have tried out various examples and wrote my own for both the simulation environment and the real hardware. I have only been experimenting with self contained networks that, for example, measure the temperature difference between two nodes and then communicate that data with other devices (PCs) over plain text RS232 link, blink LEDs, and such simple stuff.

Now I want to make a more complicated system where instead of just forwarding the data in plain text to be read on a console I would forward it to an application that would in turn post it to some sort of web service and, vice versa, receive data from web service to be delivered to nodes on the network. There is quite a lot of examples and tutorials describing this kind of setup but all of them (as far as I am aware) are focusing on the IP(v6) stack  and SLIP to achieve this. The problem with this is that I have a *really* lousy programmer and uploading of a 50 kB image takes about 1.5 mins so the development cycle is pure hell. I am also out of luck with simulation since my platform is not really supported at the moment.

That's why I decided to try out the Rime stack, image size is 1/3 of the IPv6 and the development cycle is somewhat acceptable now (I really should get a decent JTAG programmer...) Meanwhile, I am having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around this new setup with a different network stack on which there is very little information around. Although it is pretty easy to understand by itself, I am not sure how I would go about connecting a Rime network to an IP network and if it was even possible or advised/intended by it's designers.

I have some ideas in my head, ranging from ad hoc communication over a serial link between a server application running on the PC and the collector node, to a real Rime border router that is certainly outside of my league, for now.

How would you go about it? It would certainly work for my simple experimental case to just have a collector node that gathers the data from the Rime network and sends the aggregated data over a serial connection to the custom application that does the rest of the magic, but, I wouldn't want to be the guy that reinvented the wheel and I am quite sure that Rime wasn't designed to be used in a vacuum so there must be at least an advised way of doing this?

Comment: Application-layer proxying over the serial line is basically the way to go. At least I'm not aware of any solutions that would allow to bridge IP with Rime at lower layers. I'm also not aware of any generic application-layer over-serial-line implementations, possibly because each application has different requirements. The generic stuff such as framing and checksums is pretty simple to implement on your own.

Comment: Thank you for putting it in proper terms, it made the whole thing much clearer to me. 
I was overthinking about my problem and misunderstood the stack. In my simple scenario, with a single controller mote and a couple of remotes, it will be enough to forward the application messages over serial line and proxy them to the Internet server and the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Rime is a really simple stack (By simple I mean few functionnality). But it's quite quicker for simple task.
You need to program the Rime stack on your gateway. Thus, your board and the gateway can communicate with the same stack. So now you have the data send on your gateway. The gateway now can send the data with IP to whoever you want.

If you want more technical detail, then edit your question with more specific technical context.

Btw JTAG is a must have. (for industrial application)

Edit : An other solution is to simply send your data from your board to your gateway in broadcast. Then the gateway take the data and interpret it. The cons of this method is you have to somehow be sure that your gateway interpret only the data of your board (not of others board)

Comment: This makes sense. I suppose I would need to combine the Contiki native platform on the gateway to get the Rime stack and traditional UNIX sockets to get IP connectivity? But, how to implement the physical layer connectivity between the gateway and the board? This is done with SLIP in case when both ends run an IP stack, but I haven't seen SLRime yet :). 

I would like to be able to ask a more specific question but for now I am just trying to get a big picture understanding of all the parts and how they are connected. Perhaps you know of an example system that I could learn from?

Comment: @Viktor The radio stack is totally independent of upper stack (Rime/IP). So if you use for example a CC2420, contiki already manage it and you just have to call it with NETSTACk_RADIO.send()/init(). For slip-radio i don't know if they implemented it on your board/Gateway. Check it. If they did then all its ok and you have nothing to do for the radio layer. Either, you'll need to implement it (for you gateway AND your board). Obviously both must use the same radio.